# VB.NET class to C# conversion fails

Tags: c#

I learning C# and coverted a small bit of code from VB.NET to C# from DeveloperFusion but C# isn't accepting it. Here's the code...

```
namespace MP3Strip
{
    public class listViewDoubleBuffered : ListView
    {
        public listViewDoubleBuffered()
        {
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        }
    }
}
```

: ListView and this.DoubleBuffered both have red lines underneath them. How do I fix this?

Comment: You're missing an `using` statement.

Comment: What using statement do I need and where do I use it at? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your file, add the  `System.Windows.Controls` namespace.

```
using System.Windows.Controls

namespace MP3Strip
{ 
  public class listViewDoubleBuffered : ListView
  {
      public listViewDoubleBuffered()
      {
          this.DoubleBuffered = true;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I had to use System.Windows.Forms and that seemed to work. Thanks for helping!